# paypal sdk Touch id Authentication in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, touch-id

I have integrated Paypal sdk for payment in my iOS app -coded with Objective C. My client want to have paypal Authentication with Touch ID. 
As per My understanding Its only possible if Paypal- sdk provides Authentication method with Touch Id.

Though Touch Authentication is available in Paypal app, I am not able to find any where in PayPal sdk document if its available in SDK or not.  Can any one help me in finding if its available with PayPAl SDK  and if available, How to enable it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As per I know still PayPal has not integrated yet. You can read discussion in below link

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/228

And also below link is person that working with PayPal you can ask him my email

https://github.com/dgoldman-ebay

Or mail to support team of PayPal they will give you right direction.

Other way is **(Not sure it is right or not)**

Manually integrated touchId in your app When user successfully login by PayPal then his/her credential store in model/locally and when he/she will come next time to use PayPal then they will use touchID and touch view will display. After get success in touch recognize you will manually pass PayPal credential (that was stored by you in previous).

Comment: Its not possible to get credential for storing.

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/228  - I have seen this..But its old thread -closed in 2014.

Comment: Yes your are right that why I'm not sure but best way is contact with support team and explain to client same things.

Comment: Did you get any solution? Then update here because it's important question for all those developer that wants same thing like you.

Comment: Not yet, contacted PayPa- team but no response yet

Comment: I think christmas holidays are running there so you need wait till 1st jan.